# Have other countries raised serious concerns on Pakistan elections?

Tags: election, house-of-representatives, pakistan

Recently Pakistan concluded elections for its National Assembly and provincial assemblies.  I have seen the [US](https://www.state.gov/elections-in-pakistan/) and [UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/foreign-secretary-statement-pakistan-elections) official statements on these elections raising concerns on fairness.
The European Union has also raised concerns.

My question is about what other countries have to say about this election? Specifically,
statements by countries with geopolitical interests in Pakistan - specifically China, India, GCC countries, Turkey, etc.

I realize this may be too early to ask, but I'm prepared to wait for good answers.

Comment: China seldom lectures about elections (anywhere) IIRC. And so do absolutist monarchies.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone would take Indian criticism seriously based on the historical antagonism between the nations and Modi's virulent anti-Islamic attitudes. But maybe he said something anyway.

Comment: How is this not a list question like e.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/86051/are-there-other-internationally-controversial-annexations-that-china-has-refus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDK about the other countries in your list, but regarding China, the answer appears to be negative. Xinhua has a couple of reports on this; one [pre-](http://en.people.cn/n3/2024/0208/c90000-20132699.html) and one [post-election](http://en.people.cn/n3/2024/0220/c90000-20134939.html). Neither has any whiff of criticism, just official congratulations in the latter.

> China congratulates Pakistan on the **smooth and successful** holding of the general election, a Chinese Foreign Ministry spokesperson said Monday.

And despite the recent exchange of missiles, Iran's official message [was](https://english.news.cn/20240224/c821efb42bc0439ba607e22d870e71e5/c.html) rather similar with China's (but lacking the word 'smooth')... at least as Xinhua reproduced it. But Iranian's MFA [own coverage](https://en.mfa.gov.ir/portal/newsview/740388) was almost identical, so, there's that.

---

It appears to me that Turkey typically waits for a new PM to be sworn in before making any statements. However Erdogan congratulated both Imran Khan ([in 2018](http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2018-08/01/c_137360150.htm)) and Shehbaz Sharif ([in 2022](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/politics/turkish-president-congratulates-pakistans-new-prime-minister/2561163)), even if the latter was elected [by parliament] in circumstances that Khan described as a 'coup'. Erdogan's 2022 statement however just said "that Pakistan did not give up on democracy and the rule of law, despite all the difficulties and obstacles they have faced". So, one might expect something similar is going to come out of Turkey after the 2024 general elections, once a PM is sworn in.

The fairly brief AA.tr latest [coverage](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/pakistan-s-parliament-to-elect-new-prime-minister-on-march-3/3151313) of the post-election negotiations doesn't mention criticisms either. However, a longer piece from the [same day](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/pakistan-s-newly-elected-parliament-set-to-open/3150179) does quote internal Pakistani criticisms:

> Earlier, [president] Alvi had refused to summon the session, arguing that the house is incomplete since the Election Commission of Pakistan has not allotted reserved seats for women and religious minorities to the Sunni Ittehad Council (SIC), a new home to jailed former Prime Minister Imran Khan’s Pakistan Tehreek-e-Insaf (PTI) party.
>
> The president approved the summoning of the National Assembly session with "reservations” and with the hope that the issue of reserved seats would be resolved in line with the constitution, said a statement from the President's Office. [...]
>
> Expressing disappointment over the "tone and allegations" leveled in the summary sent by caretaker Prime Minister Anwaarul Haq Kakar, the president said he cannot ignore "irregularities in the electoral process and the formation of the government."
>
> [President] Alvi, who belongs to the PTI, contended that he had returned the caretaker prime minister's previous summary in line with the constitution. [...] The PTI, which supported Alvi’s decision to not summon the sitting, however, has announced that its affiliated lawmakers will attend the inaugural session to take their oaths of office.

And AA coverage from Feb 22 [reports](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/pakistan-imran-khan-backed-candidates-join-little-known-party-to-gain-numbers/3144585) 'rigging allegations' too:

> The candidates have claimed there was massive rigging in the election and its "mandate was stolen."
>
> The government as well as the electoral body have denied any wrongdoing.

And AA coverage from [Feb 20](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/pakistani-premier-warns-against-pressuring-civil-servants-amid-allegations-of-poll-rigging/3142359) was perhaps the most accusatory.

> The crucial Feb. 8 elections, **marred by violence** and rigging charges, have resulted in a hung parliament with no party securing two thirds of the seats to form a government with a simple majority, triggering an intense race to stitch together coalitions.

So, as you can see, AA reports on the internal Pakistani disputes [generally] matter-of-factly, but in much more detail than what I could find on Xinhua. The official press agency is still not [Turkish] government position, though.